# Add Jackson ObjectMapper to Swagger

Tags: java, maven, jackson, swagger, mixins

We are using Swagger to document our REST API.

We use the various swagger annotations in our Spring REST controllers

```
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/blah")
@Api("Blah")
public class SomeRestController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/some_endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ApiOperation(code = CREATED, value = "Some operation",
        response = SomeResponseClass.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = CREATED, message = "etc")
    })
    public DeferredResult<SomeResponseClass> doSomething(
        @RequestBody final SomeRequest req) {

        // do stuff

    }
}
```

When the documentation is generated it includes all data objects we use and their definitions which include all the fields.  However we want to configure how the fields in our data objects are displayed in the Swagger documentation.  For example, we may want to camel case the field name.

Putting Swagger to one side for the moment I know we can use Jackson annotations to configure the fields the way we want (using `@JsonProperty("")`).  We want to separate this from data objects using mixins and then register the mixins to the data object using a jackson ObjectMapper.

My question is how to register this ObjectMapper with Swagger so that the documentation is generated as per the annotations?

An answer from [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/kKM546QXGY0) looks promising but I have no idea where I should add this converter factory class that is mentioned in the answer.  I don't know how Swagger startup is configured.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I actually answer your question... but here is how you configure Jackson mixins within Spring Boot (I assume you use Spring Boot).

I will take for example this class:

```
public class Something {

    private String fieldA;
    private Integer fieldB;

    // getters, setters, hashCode...
}
```

I want to serialize `fieldA` as `field_a`, and I want to ignore `fieldB`. First, I create a mixin for Jackson:

```
public interface SomethingMixin {

    @JsonProperty("field_a")
    String getFieldA();

    @JsonIgnore
    Integer getFieldB();
}
```

Then I will configure my `ObjectMapper` for Spring with a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();

        builder.mixIn(Something.class, SomethingMixin.class);

        // Equivalent to your Google thread:
        // builder.propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE)

        return builder;
    }
}
```

It should use this configuration for all default `ObjectMapper`, Swagger documentation included (tested with `springfox-swagger`).

Comment: Thanks.  We don't use springfox as far as I can tell.  We also don't use this JacksonConfiguration class you have there.  Instead of the builder.mixIn() call we have a call to addMixin() within our object mapper's constructor.